# Linq Help for grouping a table

Tags: linq

I have master table Account, with Id(PK), CustomerId(FK) and AccountNumber.

A customer can have "n" number of Account.

```
Account
--------
1   |   1   |  93839200
2   |   1   |  93839201
3   |   1   |  93839202
4   |   2   |  93839200
```

Another table is AccountStatus with Id(PK), AccountId(FK), status and statusDate.

```
AccountStatus 
--------------
1 | 1 | Created | 1/1/2013
2 | 1 | Verified| 2/1/2013
3 | 2 | Created | 9/1/2013
4 | 2 | Rejected| 11/1/2013
5 | 2 | Deleted | 12/1/2013
6 | 3 | Deleted | 12/1/2013
```

Satus of account will get inserted in this table with a status date.

I need a Linq statement to pick the latest Bank status for a CustomerID.

i.e if I Pass CustomerID as 1 I need to get the latest status of the BankAccount like

```
2 | 1 | Verified| 2/1/2013
5 | 2 | Deleted | 12/1/2013
6 | 3 | Deleted | 12/1/2013
```

Comment: Is it LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities or LINQ to Objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var results = from a in Accounts
              join s in AccountStatuses on a.ID equals s.AccountID
              group new { a, s } by a.CustomerID into g
              let i = g.OrderByDescending(i => i.s.StatusDate).FirstOrDefault()
              select new
              {
                  AccountId = i.a.ID,
                  CustomerID = i.a.CustomerID,
                  Status = i.s.Status,
                  StatusDate = i.s.StatusDate
              };
```